# Cakephp 3: ordenar tabla principal por campo de sub tabla (contain)

Tags: cakephp

Necesito saber si es posible ordenar la tabla "sales" por el campo "date" de la relacionada "SaleBooking".

```
$query = $this->_salesTable->find()
            ->where([
                'product_id IN'     => $ids,
                'status IN'         => $status,
                'type IN'           => $types
            ])
            ->select([
                'id',
                'product_id',
                'entity_id',
                'Sales.type',
                'status',
                'quantity',
            ])
            ->contain([
                'Product',
                'SaleBooking'
            ]);
```

He intentando con el siguiente código pero me ordena los registros del contain y lo que necesito es ordenar la tabla principal por un campo de la tabla relacionada:

```
  $query->contain(['SaleBooking' => ['sort' => ['SaleBooking.date' => 'DESC']]]);
```

El modelo es:

```
 class SalesTable extends FilterTable
  {
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('sa_sales');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('SaleBooking', [
            'className' => 'SaleBookings',
            'foreignKey' => 'sale_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'propertyName' => 'saleBookings',
        ]);
     }
   }

 class SaleBookingsTable extends BaseTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('sa_sale_bookings');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('BookingSale', [
            'className' => 'Sales',
            'foreignKey' => 'sale_id',
            'propertyName' => 'saleBookings'
        ]);

    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda por anticipado.
saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo llamas en el `contain` puedes hacerlo sin ningún problema con la función `order`

```
$query = $this->_salesTable->find()
    ->where([
        'product_id IN'     => $ids,
        'status IN'         => $status,
        'type IN'           => $types
    ])
    ->select([
        'id',
        'product_id',
        'entity_id',
        'Sales.type',
        'status',
        'quantity',
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Product',
        'SaleBooking'
    ])
    ->order([
        'SaleBooking.date' => 'DESC'
    ]);
```

Como consejo aparte, siempre es mejor llamar a los campos con su respectivo alias por ejemplo `'Sales.id'` según corresponda

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ya había probado con ese código pero retorna "column not found".

Comment: Hola, ya he añadido el modelo.